# Comparing two different properties in GQL

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gql

The following two GQL queries work:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE FirstName = "John"
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Rating > 4.0
```

But, when I combine them...

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE FirstName = "John" AND Rating > 4.0
```

... I get an empty result set even though running the queries individually finds the entity that I am looking for. How do I compare more than one property?

Here's what I've done:

- I made sure that at least one entity exists where both is true.

[image: gql]

- I created an index for the properties:

[image]

Comment: Are the first two result sets disjoint? (i.e. the intersection is empty?)

Comment: No, there should be one result in the intersection.

Comment: People down vote without leaving a reason why. If you leave a reason, I can work on making this a better question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patrick Costello at Google answered my question:

> You need an index on exactly (FirstName, Rating). Your current index cannot answer that query.

Basically, the problem was that I created an index on all the properties. However, each "type" of query (in this case, a query comparing FirstName and Rating) needs its own index (i.e. an index with just FirstName and Rating). I hope this helps someone!